# Public Bug portal for TFS

Tags: tfs, bug-tracking

My company is transitioning it's scrum workflow into TFS.  Presently we have a public site where people can submit bug reports.  We would love to have those bug reports go directly into TFS.  Is there any add-on, or 3rd party product that supports a public bug portal into TFS?

Comment: The Tfs API is fairly simple, it's not hard to push bugs into Tfs from a form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some capability built in for that within Team Web Access.  This MSDN article can point you in the right direction:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668124.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't really fill our needs, but it appears to be the best option available with TFS.